# How to query to calculate the quantity times the price using Django ORM

Tags: django, model, aggregate, django-queryset

I would like to know how to get the total price of: quantity times price in Django ORM, and which variable to use for template to view the value?

The post is submitted successfully, but cannot get the total price: this is what I have in my views.py: 
    context={
    "tickets": Ticket.objects.all(),

"total":Ticket.objects.filter(purchaser=User.objects.get(id=request.session['user_id'])).aggregate(total_cost=Sum(F('price')*F('quantity'), output_field=FloatField())
    }
    return render(request, 'first_app/confirmation.html', context)

This is in my models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Sum, Aggregate, F

class User(models.Model):
first_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
last_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
email=models.CharField(max_length=100)
password=models.CharField(max_length=100)
created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Ticket(models.Model):
venue=models.CharField(max_length=100)
quantity=models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
price=models.DecimalField(default=25.00, max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, 
null=True, blank=True)
loop=models.CharField(max_length=100)
purchaser = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="purchases", 
on_delete=models.PROTECT)
created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

How do you query ORM to get the total quantity * price? Should that query be included before or after you do the "ticket" key in context? Should that query be added the Ticket model field? Each each is hardcoded as $25.00 as shown in models. Thank you, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you can do this.

1) You can use `.annotate()`.

```
from django.db.models import F

tickets = Ticket.objects.all().annotate(total_price=F('total_quantity') * F('price'))

for t in tickets:
    print(t.total_price)
```

2) Or, you can do the calculation in a model method:

```
...
def total_price(self):
    return self.total_quantity * self.price

print(Ticket.objects.all()[0].total_price)
```

========================================

If you follow method #1, you can access this via a context:

**view**

```
...
tickets = Ticket.objects.all().annotate(total_price=F('total_quantity') * F('price'))
return render(request, 'template.html', {"tickets": tickets}
```

**template**

```
{% for ticket in tickets %}
    ticket.total_price
{% endfor %}
```

If you follow method #2

**view**

```
...
tickets = Ticket.objects.all()
return render(request, 'template.html', {"tickets": tickets}
```

**template**

```
{% for ticket in tickets %}
    ticket.total_price
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: context={
        "tickets": Ticket.objects.all().aggregate(total_price=F('quantity') * F('price'), output_field=FloatField())
    }---error: QuerySet.aggregate() received non-expression(s): <django.db.models.fields.FloatField>. I added FloatField, F in models.py. The 'quantity' =PositiveInteger and 'price'=DecimalField type and not sure if it's possible to output it in FloatField? Does the calculation model above go directly below the Ticket model or do I need a add a field for that one? Thank you Hybrid!

Comment: @Keiko The error is telling you you cant use `FloatField` because it isn't an expression. You need to check the aggregated price ("total_price") in your template by looping over each ticket in tickets, and then calling `ticket.total_price`

Comment: Thank you Hybrid. I've done the above suggestions and I keep getting the "Expression contains mixed types. You must set output_field." since 'quantity' is a PositiveInteger field and 'price' is DecimalField from models.py....to what output_field should I put if FloatField did not work? I appeciate your help.

Comment: @Keiko My bad! I didnt realize the fields were different types. Try this line: `tickets = Ticket.objects.all().annotate(total_price=Sum(F('total_quantity') * F('price'), output_field=FloatField()))`

Comment: Oh my goodness, you saved my life! Thank you for your patience! I'm going to try to figure how to add the sales tax now. Would you suggest I add a taxes field in models.py or should I just include it the query?

Comment: No problem! I would just add the final price/sales tax into the annotation to keep things tidy. If this answer solved your question, feel free to click the "check" mark next to my answer. It will help other people who are looking for a working answer!

Comment: I did another key in views.py: "sales_tax": Ticket.objects.all().annotate(tax=Sum(F('quantity') * F('price')*0.0725,  output_field=FloatField())), but it when it comes to calculating the grand total of total amount + sales tax that is tricky. I added another key for grand_total: "grand_total": Ticket.objects.all().annotate(total=Sum(F('quantity') * F('price')*0.0725+total_price,  output_field=FloatField())), but that didn't work. I'll definitely checkmark the answer for you!

Comment: Try this: `tickets = Ticket.objects.all().annotate(tax=ExpressionWrapper(F('quantity') * F('price') * 0.0725, output_field=FloatField())).annotate(total_price=ExpressionWrapper(F('quantity') * F('price') + F('tax'), output_field=FloatField()))` and import `ExpressionWrapper` from the same place as `F`

Comment: Also, the check mark should be right under the "down" arrow to the left of my main post (it should be grey!)

Comment: Wow, got it! I learned so much. Thank you! I finally found the arrow hehe.

Comment: Glad to hear! I hope I was able to answer all of your questions. This place is amazing for help, and if you ever need more, don't hesitate to break your question into parts and create new posts. Good luck!